# PHP, MYSQL, EXPLODE and ARRAYS

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

```
$query_posts = "
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Product'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query_posts) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['meta_value'];
}
```

The above produces a list of results as below:

```
235/40/R18/95/ZR(Y)/XL £180.00
225/45/R17/94/W/XL £180.00
235/45/R17/97/Y/XL £180.00
245/45/R17/99/Y/XL £180.00
245/40/R17/91/Y £180.00
225/40/R18/92/W/XL £180.00
etc etc
```

They are tyre sizes if you didn't guess.  I need to break the first three values into distinct relational menus: Trye Width  /  Sidewall /  Rim

I worked out that if I use:

```
$query_posts = "
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Product'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query_posts) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tyres_widths = (explode("/",$row['meta_value']));
    echo ($tyres_widths[0]); 
}
```

I can get the first ($tyres_widths[0]), second ($tyres_widths[1]) or third column ($tyres_widths[2]), but the values are not distinct and of course I have still not got to the point when they are relational in menus.

Is my approach correct? There has got to be a better method? Can someone assist.  I am happy to reward for correct answer and of course someone else can benefit which is the whole point!!

Thanks in advance

Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another approach would be regular expressions, I wouldn't recommend it though because it quite resource "eating", what you could do is climb the array and name the array as it climbs
using functions as first, next, end

you can find the diffrent functions behavior at php.net/next alt. php.net/function name

p.s. hope it helped

```
$array = (explode("/",$row['meta_value']));
$tires['width']= first($array);
$tires['height']= next($array);
$tires['depth']= next($array);
```

etc continue climbing the array and name them as you please it returns false if there is nothing more to get

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. Note that you can use `list` to "unpack" the array:

```
list($width, $sidewall, $rim) = explode("/",$row['meta_value']);
```

A variable named `$sidewall` is clearer than a variable named `$tire_widths[1]`.

**EDIT**

Even tidier, you can put the fields back in an associative array, using:

```
list($tires['width'], 
     $tires['sidewall'], 
     $tires['rim'])      = explode("/",$row['meta_value']);
```

**EDIT**

Per request in comment, to create a list of distinct values for a specific field, you will have to create a seperate array and use `array_unique`:

```
$result = mysql_query($query_posts) or die(mysql_error());
$ar_widths = array(); // setup array of widths

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    list($width, $sidewall, $rim) = explode("/",$row['meta_value']);

    $ar_widths[] = $width; // remember width
}

$ar_widths = array_unique($ar_widths); // remove duplicates
print_r($ar_widths);
```

Comment: This is helpful, when I unpack how can I just get unique/distinct results though?

Comment: What do you mean by distinct results? You unpack each row seperately. The variable names will correspond to the different fields.

Comment: If I echo the width (echo $width;), the results are not distinct(unique): 

235
225
235
245
245
225
225
245
255
255
265

How would I achieve this, been messing with array_unique, but with not success.

Comment: Your code works great. I was so so so close, but not close enough for it to be right!  Not sure how I am going to make the menus relational.. any ideas?

I have three unique arrays now, $ar_widths, $ar_sidewalls and $ar_rims.

Comment: Tomas, I would like to Paypal you some beer/coffee money. What address can I send it to?

Comment: I'm glad to help Stuart, no beers necessary. Thanks. Maybe accept the answer?

Comment: Of course, but I still need to figure out the relational array menus.  Should I be heading towards JavaScript land?

Comment: What do you mean with relational menu? You mean a menu on the website? How should it behave? What are the items?

Comment: So we built four arrays, the orginal array from the database results ($ar_tyres[] = $row['meta_value'];) then, we build three additional arrays ($ar_widths[] = $row['meta_value']; $ar_sidewalls and $ar_rims).

I can make three menus with the values we have obtained. BUT I want the menus to be relational menus, so only display sidewalls that exist for the tyre widths and the same for rims.  Do you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes. I see what you mean. This involves JavaScript. I would suggest using JQuery. You can go two ways depending on the amount of data and required performance. Either you generate a menu of widths and perform an AJAX request to get the data for the second menu on click. Or you can generate all menus and hide all second and third level menus. Then you would make the onclick handler of the first menu selectively show values of the first menu.

Comment: For a more elaborate answer, maybe you should try creating a a new question, cause this not really belong here in these comments...

Comment: No problem, thank you so so much for your help Tomas. Hope it helps someone else, it is full and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "array_unique" function to remove duplicate elements from the array.